# Fail to Deploy : Natural Language Classifier Toolkit - Bluemix / IBM watson

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

Has anyone used the natural language classifier on bluemix?
I do the following steps but it fails to deploy. Has anyone experienced this?

1. Go to https://hub.jazz.net/project/wdctools/ibmwatson-nlc-groundtruth/overview
2. Click on "Deploy to Bluemix"
3. After clicking "Deploy to Bluemix" button, the next page shows this:

> Created project successfully
>
> Cloned repository successfully
>
> Configured pipeline successfully
>
> Deploy to Bluemix failed

**Requested log information - Moved from an answer into the question by an editor**

This is in answer to Ben Rondeau's request for a log. I don't have enough rep points to add this as a comment :(

The IBMWATSON-NLC-GROUNDTRUTH build gets quite far along and passes a bunch of tests. It appears to have some trouble getting bower set up, but eventually that is resolved. This is the build step that fails:

Running "karma:unit" (karma) task

```
WARN [watcher]: Pattern "/home/pipeline/15b6190d-56a3-42f6-b703-f60379620682/client/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js" does not match any file.
WARN [watcher]: Pattern "/home/pipeline/15b6190d-56a3-42f6-b703-f60379620682/client/bower_components/ibmwatson-common-ui-components/dist/ibmwatson-common-ui-components.js" does not match any file.
WARN [watcher]: Pattern "/home/pipeline/15b6190d-56a3-42f6-b703-f60379620682/client/app/app.coffee" does not match any file.
WARN [watcher]: Pattern "/home/pipeline/15b6190d-56a3-42f6-b703-f60379620682/client/app/**/*.coffee" does not match any file.
WARN [watcher]: Pattern "/home/pipeline/15b6190d-56a3-42f6-b703-f60379620682/client/app/**/*.jade" does not match any file.
WARN [watcher]: Pattern "/home/pipeline/15b6190d-56a3-42f6-b703-f60379620682/client/components/**/*.coffee" does not match any file.
WARN [watcher]: Pattern "/home/pipeline/15b6190d-56a3-42f6-b703-f60379620682/client/components/**/*.jade" does not match any file.
INFO [karma]: Karma v0.12.37 server started at http://localhost:8080/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS
INFO [PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Linux 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket 6VJzDkVVigia7YxR5zfc with id 20079085
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 0 of 64 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0 secs)
AKPhantomJS 1.9.8 (Linux 0.0.0) Service: authentication should exist FAILED
    Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ng due to:
    TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'Function.prototype.bind.apply')
        at instantiate (/home/pipeline/15b6190d-56a3-42f6-b703-f60379620682/client/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4619)
        at provider (/home/pipeline/15b6190d-56a3-42f6-b703-f60379620682/client/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4433)
        at /home/pipeline/15b6190d-56a3-42f6-b703-f60379620682/client/bower_components/angular/angular.js:365
        at forEach (/home/pipeline/15b6190d-56a3-42f6-b703-f60379620682/client/bower_components/angular/angular.js:335)
        at /home/pipeline/15b6190d-56a3-42f6-b703-f60379620682/client/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4423
        at ngModule (/home/pipeline/15b6190d-56a3-42f6-b703-f60379620682/client/bower_components/angular/angular.js:2475)
        at invoke (/home/pipeline/15b6190d-56a3-42f6-b703-f60379620682/client/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4604)
        at runInvokeQueue (/home/pipeline/15b6190d-56a3-42f6-b703-f60379620682/client/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4497)
        at /home/pipeline/15b6190d-56a3-42f6-b703-f60379620682/client/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4506
        at forEach (/home/pipeline/15b6190d-56a3-42f6-b703-f60379620682/client/bower_components/angular/angular.js:321)
        at loadModules (/home/pipeline/15b6190d-56a3-42f6-b703-f60379620682/client/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4529)
        at createInjector (/home/pipeline/15b6190d-56a3-42f6-b703-f60379620682/client/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4409)
        at workFn (/home/pipeline/15b6190d-56a3-42f6-b703-f60379620682/client/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2799
```

Comment: Can you post the logs from the deployment? Navigate to your Bluemix DevOps dashboard, click on the repo and then the build/deploy button. You will see a red box on the deploy stage and clicking on it with show the logs.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reporting this issue. A dependency on a certain library was not being handled in all cases, hence the errors. That's been resolved, and the updated source is now available. Please delete the Bluemix app that was created for you and the instance of the Natural Language Classifier that it created for you, and re-try the "Deploy to Bluemix" button. The build/deploy process should now work correctly. Sorry for the inconvenience!